# How do I give the main section of my site a 2 column layout so that it looks good?

Tags: html, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

Below I will add my HTML and CSS code. I want to give my page a 2 column layout within the main section. Any help is much appreciated. The navigation, footer, and title part will be the same on each page. I just need the two-column on the main section.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>

    <title>Augie's Custom T-shirts</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link href="Style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    
    
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="nav">
        <div class="menu">
            <p>Home</p>
        </div>
        <div class="menu">
            <p>Shop</p>
        </div>
        <div class="menu">
            <p>Events</p>
        </div>
        <div class="menu">
            <p>Contact Us</p>
        </div>
        <br/>
        <br/>
    </nav>
    <main class="wrapper">

        <div class="banner">
            <h1><span class="name">Augie's Custom T-shirts</span></h1>
            <h2>Custom T-shirts for you or your party.</h2>
            
            <div class="bulletPoints">
            
                <ul>
                    <li>Birthday parties</li>
                    <li>Vacation groups</li>
                    <li>Bachelorette Parties</li>
                    <li>Family reunions</li>
                    <li>Work team rewards</li>
                    <li>Business promotions</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <br/>
            
            
        </div>
    <p id="Catch">          
    Do you have an event coming up, and want everyone to get in the spirit?  T-shirts can bring a group together, make everyone feel connected, and let everyone know what you're celebrating.
    </p>

    <p>T-shirts can also be a great gift to someone that acknowledges their special interest or hobby.</p>

    <p>Choose from one of our unique designs, or let us put your own design on a shirt for you.</p>
    
            <div class="row">
                <div class="column">
                    <img src="images/gorilla.jpg" alt="Gorilla" style="width:100%">
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <img src="images/pink.jpg" alt="Pink" style="width:100%">
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <img src="images/skull.jpg" alt="Skull" style="width:100%">
                </div>
            </div>
            
    <p><strong>How it works:</strong></p>

    <p>Browse our selection of unique designs, select the size and colors of the shirts you would like, and place your order.  We will ship your shirts within three business days for in-stock shirts, or five days for custom size and colors.</p>
        
        <figure>
        <img src="images/t-shirt-colors.jpeg" alt="T-shirt colors" class="image1">
        <figcaption>Choose from are variety of t-shirt colors!</figcaption>
        </figure>
        
    <p>Have a design of your own?  Can't find the right sentiment?  Call or email us to discuss the possibilities or get some ideas for your event.</p>

    <p>Please note there will be a one time $15 charge for any custom graphics design.</p>
    


    
        <h2><em>Contact us today!</em></h2>
    
    
    </main>
    
    <footer class="footer">
        <div class="box">
            <p>Augie's Custom T-shirts</p>
            <p>(478) 555-1212</p>
            <p>augieB@augiesTees.com</p>
            <br/>
        </div>
        <div class="box">
            <p>Check out are Social Media for updates!</p>
            <p>Facebook:</p>
            <p>Instagram:</p>
            <p>Twitter:</p>
        </div>
        <div class="box">
            <p>Locations:</p>
            <br/>
            <p>100 Tanger Dr, Locust Grove, GA</p>
            <p>2954 Watson Blvd Suite 100, Warner Robins, GA</p>
        </div>
    </footer>
    
    <div class="copyright">
        <h3> @copyright: Landon Byrd</h3>
        <p>Fall 2021, All Rights Reserved</p>
    </div>
    
<p>
    <a href="http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/check/referer">
        <img style="border:0;width:88px;height:31px"
            src="http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/images/vcss"
            alt="Valid CSS!" />
    </a>
</p>


</body>
```

CSS

```
/*

Landon Byrd
Fall 2021

    Plain Red       #f60d41
    Rich Red        #f6130d
    Orioles Orange  #f64d0d
    Sunset Orange   #f6870d
    Golden Yellow   #f6c10d

*/
/* Global settings */
h1 {text-align: center; font-family: Papyrus}
h2 {text-align: center; color: #f6130d; text-decoration: underline}
.wrapper{width:85%; margin:0 auto; max-width: 960px;}

/* Nav Section */
.nav{width: 85%; margin:0 auto; background-color: #f6130d; text-align: center;}
.menu{float:left; width: 25% }

/* Main section */
.banner{justify-content: center; background-color: #f6c10d; text-align: center;}
.bulletPoints ul {
  display:inline-block;
  text-align:left;
}


section{background-color: #f6870d; color: #f60d41; font-style:italic; margin: 25px 50px 75px;}


body {
  background-image: url("images/background.jpeg");
}

.image1
{
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

figcaption {
  text-align: center;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
}

.column {
  flex: 33.33%;
  padding: 5px;
}

/* Footer section */
* {box-sizing: border-box;}
.footer{text-align: center; background-color: #f6130d; color: #f6c10d; }
.box{float:left; width: 33.33% }
.footer::after {content: ""; clear:both; }

/* Copyright section */
.copyright {text-align: center; background-color: #f6130d; color: #f6c10d; }
```

I would also like to make sure all my floats are cleared as nessicary.

Answer (score 1):

It's very easy with flex.

In 2021 you should try to avoid floats as much as possible.

Simply switch to flex as described here:

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

As for your specific case:

```css
.flex-container{
  display:flex;
  width:100%;
}

.col{
  max-width:50%;
  flex: 0 0 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="col">
    col 1
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    col 2
  </div>
</div>
```

If you want to make them go vertically on mobile, just give the container the property flex-direction:column and make the 2 divs max-width:100% and flex:0 0 100%;